# Can you instantiate a class and then assign a different class to it using new (e.g. class1 name = new class2)

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, new-operator

I was watching a c++ tutorial about the "->" operator on youtube (the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p3grlSpWYA&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=46&ab_channel=TheCherno) ) in 2:48 of the tutorial. He wrote the code

```
int main()
{ScopedPtr entity = new Entity();}
```

from what I understand about instantiating class, the class behind new keyword should be the same as the class you are instantiating. Pls explain how this work and why it work.

FYI: I'm a beginner to coding and I do not have have guide books or anything I'm currently learning C++ from the youtube channel called Cherno, and whenever I don't understand something I just search up on the internet and go into website

Comment: If `ScopedPtr` is a base class of `Entity`, then a `Entity *` can be implicitly converted to a `ScopedPtr *`.      Bear in mind that `ScopedPtr` needs to also have a `virtual` destructor, otherwise the usage of `new` cannot be matched with a `delete`  (i.e. `delete entity`) will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: `ScopePtr`, based on the name, is a pointer-like object. It will probably have a constructor that expects a `Entity *` argument which indicates which object it should point to. This example is an initialization, it is basically equivalent to `ScopedPtr entity = ScopePtr( new Entity() );` or `ScopedPtr entity( new Entity() );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it may happen for instance when you create a pointer to an implementation of your classes where `ScopedPtr` is a pointer to the implementation of `Entity`.

You could have some documentation [here](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/creating-smart-pointers-in-c/) or [here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/01/pimpl.html)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(){}
    //only for test
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << " print";
    }
};

class ScopedPtr
{
public:
    ScopedPtr(Entity* d) { implem = d;}
    ~ScopedPtr(){ delete implem;}

    //only for test
    void print()
    {
        implem->print();
    }
private:
    Entity* implem;
};

int main()
{
    ScopedPtr entity = new Entity();
    entity.print();
}
```

Comment: `ScopePtr entity = new Entity()` is likely to work fine. The name suggests it would be a pointer-like type. It probably does something like `std::unique_ptr<Entity> entity = new Entity;` or at least the initialization should work the same way. I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Sure, my bad. I read fast but you are right. it could be a pointer :). Thanks for correcting me